# Convert PowerPoint to image or movie using addin

Tags: vba, powerpoint

Is it possible to convert pptx file to image or movie using addin?

My understanding is that only converting to image using VBA add-in is supported[1], but cannot find documentation for other combinations.

Is there any official documentation explaining we cannot do this?
Or we can, actually?

| format | office-js | VBA |
| --- | --- | --- |
| image | no | yes |
| movie | no | no |

[1] https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.slide.export

Answer (score 2):

- VBA can convert ppt file to movie

```vb
ActivePresentation.CreateVideo "D:\temp\test.mp4"
```

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Presentation.CreateVideo method (PowerPoint)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.presentation.createvideo?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbapp10.chm583123)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)